# Use network drive in sftp on Windows 2016

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2016, sftp, mappeddrive

I'll start by specifying I'm not in the Sysadmin team at work, I work in another building with a small team and we are the "special cases".  So they gave me full admin on our servers but I have no knowledge/power on the rest.

I have two servers, let's call them A and B.

> **A**
>
> - Windows Server 2016
> - 35 TB of hard drives
> - Local network
>
> **B**
>
> - Windows Server 2016
> - 200 GB
> - Behind firewalls, loadbalancers and such
> - OpenSSH (Only port 22 is open)
> - Mapped drive to server A on N:

I'm trying to let someone access the files on A by using sftp to server B.  I tried symbolic links but it can't locate the folder when using WinSCP.  I can't put the files on B since we have about 30 TB of data.

Any ideas?  Thank you

Comment: Is the OpenSSH server running as a service? In what context is the network drive mapped?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Mapping a drive to a letter often gets messy. For example, it might be mapped for an interactive user, but not for a service account. Try referring to the files directory on A via a UNC path instead of a letter drive. That is, as `\\A\ShareName\Directory\ `, not as  `N:\Directory`.

Comment: @DougDeden I get an error 4 if I change the symbolic link to the UNC, ssh stops working if I use it on the ChrootDirectory config.

Comment: @eKKiM The OpenSSH is running as local admin... I'll try switching it to the ssh user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @eKKiM for the hint!

I couldn't run the service as the wanted SSH user, but by using the method used here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867064/3549186 I created a task to map the drive as the local System account and for the SSH user.

The symbolic link works perfectly now.

Comment: Could you flag that as an answer?